# Evaluating a slow sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

In my integration adventures, I came across this sum which I could not simplify:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}\log(2n+1)}{2n+1}$$

[Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%5B%28-1%29%5En%20log%282n%2b1%29/%282n%2b1%29,%7Bn,1,oo%7D%5D) seems to believe the sum diverges and is not of much help here.

Does a closed form for this sum exist?  If not, can this sum be transformed nicely that has faster convergence?

Comment: Are you sure this series converges? To use Leibnitz test. for example, you'd have to make sure the general term without that $\,(-1)^n\,$ is monotone descending to zero...?

Comment: @DonAntonio It seems to suffice the Alternating Series Test (http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/AlternatingSeries.aspx)

Comment: Exactly my point, Argon: Alternating Series Test = Leibnitz Test.

Comment: @DonAntonio So it seems like it does converge, yes.

Comment: As long as you can prove the monotone descending convergence, yes: it does.

Comment: The closed form found by Sasha is ideal. As far as accelerating the sum goes, [Euler's transformation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerTransform.html) works quite well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using $$\frac{\log(2n+1)}{2n+1} = -\lim_{s \to 1^+} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^s}$$
as well as absolute convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (2n+1)^{-s}$ for $s>1$ we get
$$\begin{eqnarray}
   \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{\log(2n+1)}{2n+1} &=& -\lim_{s \to 1^+} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (2n+1)^{-s} \\ &=& -\lim_{s \to 1^+} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s} \left(2^{-2 s} \left( \zeta\left(s,\frac{1}{4}\right) - \zeta\left(s,\frac{3}{4}\right)  \right) \right) 
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Using $\zeta(s,a) = \frac{1}{s-1} - \psi(a) + \gamma_1(a)(s-1) + \mathcal{o}(s-1)$, where $\psi(a)$ is the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function), and $\gamma_1(a)$ is the first generalized [Stieltjes constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants), we get:
$$
   \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{\log(2n+1)}{2n+1} = \frac{\pi}{2} \log(2) + \frac{1}{4} \left( \gamma_1\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) - \gamma_1\left(\frac{3}{4}\right) \right)
$$
the same combination of generalized Stieltjes constants appeared in [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324637) of mine, leading to the following closed form for the sum:
$$
   \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{\log(2n+1)}{2n+1} = - \frac{\pi}{4} \left( \gamma +  \log \left( \frac{4 \pi^3}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^4} \right) \right) \approx -0.1929013\color\gray{167969124}
$$

Comment: WOW!  You always answer my questions fantastically, thanks!

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio i am encoutering the same question like that, but instead of $(2k+1)$, it is $(2k+1)^3$. Can you try this one? Thank you.

Comment: Same technique is going to apply. Do you see how to tweak the value `s` approaches in the limit to solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

I would like to propose a slightly different approach.
 
For $\text{Re}(s)>0$, we may introduce the Dirichlet L-function
$$\begin{eqnarray*} L(\chi_4,s)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\chi_4(n)}{n^s}&=&\sum_{k\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{(4k+1)^s}-\frac{1}{(4k+3)^s}\right)\\&=&\prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{\chi_4(p)}{p^s}\right)^{-1} \tag{A}\end{eqnarray*}$$
and notice that the value of the given series just depends on $\frac{d}{ds}L(\chi_4,s)$ at $s=1$, i.e.
$$ L'(\chi_4,1) = L(\chi_4,1)\cdot\frac{L'(\chi_4,1)}{L(\chi_4,1)}=\frac{\pi}{4}\sum_{p}\frac{\log p}{p\cdot\chi_4(p)-1}.\tag{B}$$
On the other hand, by the (inverse) Laplace transform we have
$$ L(\chi_4,s) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}\,dx}{2\cosh x}\tag{C}$$
hence:
$$ L'(\chi_4,s) = \frac{\pi\gamma}{4}+\color{blue}{\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{2\cosh x}\,dx} \tag{D}$$
and the whole problem boils down to the evaluation of the blue integral, which is clearly related to the [Gudermannian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function) by integration by parts. According to Gradshteyn-Rizhyk 4.371 we actually have
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{2\cosh x}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{4}\,\log\,\left(\frac{4\pi^3}{\Gamma\left(\tfrac{1}{4}\right)^4}\right)\tag{E}$$
leading to an unexpected closed form for the RHS of $(B)$, too. I guess that a proof of $(E)$ can be derived from differentiating the [reflection formula](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/dirichlet-l-function/) for the involved Dirichlet L-function.

Answer (score 0):

I get
(modulo algebra errors)
that it does converge.

Pair the odd and even terms:

If
$t(n)
=\frac{(-1)^{n}\log(2n+1)}{2n+1}
$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
t(2n-1)+t(2n)
&=\frac{(-1)^{2n-1}\log(2(2n-1)+1)}{2(2n-1)+1}+\frac{(-1)^{2n}\log(2(2n)+1)}{2(2n)+1}\\
&=\frac{-\log(4n-1)}{4n-1}+\frac{\log(4n+1)}{4n+1}\\
&=\frac{(4n-1)\log(4n+1)-(4n+1)\log(4n-1)}{(4n-1)(4n+1)}\\
&=\frac{(4n-1)(\log(4n)+\log(1+1/(4n)))-(4n+1)(\log(4n)+\log(1-1/(4n)))}{(4n-1)(4n+1)}\\
&=\frac{-2\log(4n)+4n(\log(1+1/(4n))-\log(1-1/(4n))-\log(1+1/(4n))-\log(1-1/(4n))}{(4n-1)(4n+1)}\\
&=\frac{-2\log(4n)+4n(1/(4n)-1/(32n^2)+O(1/n^3)+(1/(4n)+1/(32n^2)+O(1/n^3))-\log(1-1/(16n^2))}{(4n-1)(4n+1)}\\
&=\frac{-2\log(4n)+4n(1/(2n)+O(1/n^3))+1/(16n^2)+O(1/n^4)}{(4n-1)(4n+1)}\\
&=\frac{-2\log(4n)+2+O(1/n^2)}{(4n-1)(4n+1)}\\
\end{array}
$

and the sum of these converge.