# The sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k \frac {\log(2k+1)}{(2k+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

What can we say about $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k\log (2k+1)}{2k+1}$? Clearly it takes a value of negative real number, and seems to be an analogy of $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}=\frac{\pi}{4}$, but I don't know the way of evaluating $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k\log (2k+1)}{2k+1}$.

Comment: Isn't it $L'(1,\chi)$ for a suitable L-function?

Comment: [It is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function#Special_values)  $L'(1,\chi_4)= \beta'(1)$. Not convinced by the given closed-form

Comment: You may want to have a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1284941/72031

Comment: As shown here (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2472198/44121), the question boils down to evaluating the integral $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{\cosh x}\,dx.$$